# Android: Checking the login status in the Application class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I wanted to implement a code that checks out the login status in the global application level, so I created an ApplicationController class that extends the Application class.

```
public class ApplicationController extends Application {

    private static ApplicationController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        if(!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            session.logout();
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

But as I run the application, it shows an error message that it cannot create the application due to the nullpointerexception. To summarise the above log, the Exceptions are thrown in the three parts of my application:

```
10-21 00:04:26.161 1397-1397/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.marshall.opensurvey.application.session.SQLiteHandler.deleteUsers(SQLiteHandler.java:129)
10-21 00:04:26.161 1397-1397/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.marshall.opensurvey.application.controller.SessionManager.logout(SessionManager.java:51)
10-21 00:04:26.161 1397-1397/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.marshall.opensurvey.application.controller.ApplicationController.onCreate(ApplicationController.java:33)
```

The first part is the following part in the ApplicationController class.

```
SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        if(!session.isLoggedIn()) {
            session.logout();
        }
```

Second, here's the SessionManager class, and the logout method is causing the NullPointerException.

```
public class SessionManager {
    // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

    // Shared Preferences
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private Editor editor;
    private Context _context;

    private SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(_context);

    // Shared pref mode
    private int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "OpenSurvey";

    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN = "isLoggedIn";

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, isLoggedIn);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();

        Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);
    }

    public void logout() {
        setLogin(false);
        db.deleteUsers();
    }
}
```

And finally, the deleteUsers() method in the logout() method above is causing the NullPointerException. the deleteUsers() method is in the SQLiteHandler class below.

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_PROFILE = "profile";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
    private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_PROFILE + " BLOB"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_BIRTHDAY + " TEXT," + KEY_AGE + " INT," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(final User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_PROFILE, user.getProfile());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_NAME, user.getName());
        values.put(KEY_BIRTHDAY, user.getBirthday());
        values.put(KEY_UID, user.getUid());
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, user.getCreatedAt());

        long id = db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "New user is added into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user.put("profile", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("birthday", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void deleteUsers() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
    }

}
```

I know that the NullPointerException is so basic and I am worried of getting negative reputations from you with this question, but I worked with it for more than 3 hours and still cannot figure out what the problem is.. so please help me.

Comment: *" I am worried of getting negative reputations from you"*. Don't be. If you are worried about rep on this site then your growth is limited. Rep here is a good thing but is not the main purpose. The issue is probably because of `private SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(_context);` this isn't inside a method and `_context` is null at this point. You might want to move the initialization inside the constructor.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanx so much! I always feel that the problems come from the very easy parts..

Comment: They usually do. And not just for beginners. I hope that helped